# Yii2 renderDynamic not working for setting form

Tags: php, caching, yii2

I have a form on the page that I am using page cache on, I need the top part of the form to render dynamically so that the csrf token changes every time, however when I put this code in

```
<?php $this->renderDynamic('return $form = ActiveForm::begin();'); ?>
```

I get this error `Call to a member function field() on a non-object` on this line

```
<?= $form->field($model, $NBAteam['id'])->checkBox(['label' => NULL, 'data-seed' => $NBAteam['seed']]) ?>
```

I also get this error in the Apache error log `Class 'ActiveForm' not found`

Comment: what about the model value? and I don't get that error without the renderDynamic, so wouldn't model be fine?

Comment: is your model loaded? check it

Comment: one of these values are having issue `$model, $NBAteam['id']`

Comment: I just used `var_dump` on both of those right before that line and they are both fine

Comment: are you sure its not a problem with `$form`

Comment: I found another error in the apache log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround as `renderDynamic` does not seem to work with Yii widgets. So I used jQuery to modify the value of the csrf token after the page is loaded from cache.

```
$this->registerJs("$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=_csrf]').val('".$this->renderDynamic('return Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;')."');
});", View::POS_END);
```